# Re-entering USA multiple times in a month using a B1/B2 visa

Tags: canada, b1-b2-visas, mexico, repeat-visits, bangladeshi-citizens

I want to visit USA from Bangladesh using my B1/B2 visa. After exploring the west coast of USA, I want to visit Vancouver in Canada from USA.

After the trip to Canada, I want to return to USA and take a flight to Mexico (flight from LA/LV to Mexico is much much cheaper than Vancouver) after my Canadian trip. Then, from Mexico, I want to enter USA again as my flight to my country is from NY.

To sum up, I will be visiting USA thrice in the span of 5 weeks. Will I face any problem in the immigration?

I have multiple entry visas for both USA and Canada.

Comment: When is this trip taking place? Canada currently has significant COVID entry restrictions. Some of those are set to be relaxed for fully vaccinated travelers on September 7th, but even that comes with some limits (such as only applying to certain vaccines), and there's at least some risk that could change or new restrictions imposed depending on what happens in the next few months that could disrupt your plans.

Comment: Hopefully you've planned this all out well but I just wanted to point out that the US is massive. Hopefully you are flying to all of these places. You made it sound like you were driving from Vancouver to Las Vegas to get a cheaper flight to Mexico. That's a 2 day drive. West coast to NY is 3-4 days of hard driving.

Comment: @ZachLipton - Thank you for pointing them. I am aware of the restrictions imposed by Canada and will be planning accordingly. I will be traveling to Canada (if the restriction is removed) during mid September and I am fully vaccinated.

Comment: @JosephYancey - Thank you for your input. Yes, I will be fly between cities and even with multiple flights, it will be much cheaper than flying to Mexico directly from Vancouver (or Toronto).

Answer (score 5):

It may depend on the visa restriction you may have, but usually you may enter and exit as many time you want.

But visa is not a guarantee you can enter in US: the immigration officer should still check if you have intention to overstay/work/etc. (in a way not permitted by your visa).

But it seems that your case is just tourism travel (and from nearby countries), and on short time (if you enter every 6 months, just few days after exiting US... this will rise a red flag). So I see no problems (if you have money to sustain you, and you are genuinely making tourism). OTOH I have no crystal ball and nobody could predict decision of the immigration officers.

Comment: I don't have any other intention other than travelling. But, I will be using USA as a point of transit to another country at least once during my trip, it might not fall under tourism but an indirect transit. That is what I am worrying about.

Comment: It is not a problem. BTW traveling is part of tourism. It doesn't matter if you are visiting US or other countries. In any case "transit" is allowed (and I did several time, just with VWP). In any case, "your intentions" are not so important, but what the immigration officer think about your intentions. If you have the ticket and you show that you entered and exited US recently (without being forced), and you didn't stay a lot in US without good reasons, there should be no problems. From your question: you have a plan and you know what you are doing (and you speak English): very good points.